# input channels vs. detected channels?

Tags: input, runtime-error, channel, grayscale, resnet

I'm training a model with ResNet50, and my inputs are grayscale images. This is the feedback I'm getting: RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 1, 3, 3], expected input[10, 64, 150, 150] to have 1 channels, but got 64 channels instead.

I've already checked with another script that all of my inputs are indeed grayscale with 1 channel, yet I'm still getting the feedback that my inputs have 64 channels. I'm not sure what is wrong and how I can fix it.